# Cómo hago un where en laravel con relaciones

Tags: laravel, filtro, relaciones

Estoy con un inconveniente en mi aplicación laravel. Necesito hacer una búsqueda de una relación pero no sé como hacerlo. Estuve dando vueltas pero todo lo que encuentro es con relación por ID, y no es lo que necesito. Entonces acá está el código que tengo ahora que está funcionando, y me faltaría agregar lo que quiero hacer, a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Tengo dos tablas:

**Users**

```
ID | name | lastname
```

**Deceased**

```
ID | name | lastname | user_id
```

Ahora, en el modelo ya hice la relación:
User:

```
public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        if ( trim( $name ) )
            return $query -> where(\DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname)"), 'LIKE', "%$name%");
    }

public function deceased()
    {
        return $this -> hasMany(Deceased::Class);
    }
```

Y en el controlador traigo los datos para mostrarlos.
Este es el controlador:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request -> get('name');

        $clients = Models\User::name( $name )
                                -> where('user_type', 3)
                                -> where('state', '!=', 4)
                                -> orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                                -> paginate(15);

        return view('clients.index', compact('clients', 'name'));
    }
```

Hasta acá todo perfecto. El scope que hago en el modelo es porque el usuario puede filtrar el listado buscando por nombre de "user". El problema es que ahora mi cliente me pide poder buscar también por nombre de "deceased" y no tengo idea cómo podría hacer para que eso.

Ideas?

Comment: Y por cuál de todas las columnas de deceased?

Comment: tendía q hace un concatenamiento de "name" y "lastname"

Comment: Pero esas columnas ya las tienes en users, por qué las repites?

Comment: cada tabla tiene su "name" y "lastname" xq son datos personas, el "user" es el usuario de la plataforma, y el "deceased" es un difunto que le corresponde al "user", no se repiten, son distintos datos.

Comment: Entonces quieres buscar tanto por el mame y lastname del user como del deceaced cualquiera de esos datos cierto?

Comment: Exacto! Ahí es donde hago aguas xq no sé cómo hacerlo en el modelo como lo hice para el caso del "user"

Comment: @OscarMorales entonces puede darse el caso de que busque por nombre de "deceased" y que no busque?

Comment: @JuanRivera calculo que te faltó al final de la pregunta algo...no obstante, respondo: el cliente en el listado tiene un filtro, es opcional, puede buscar por nombre de "user" y/o por nombre de "deceased".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es un **left join** para que las dos tablas se fusionen en una misma y entonces buscar en ella.

```php
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request -> get('name');

        $users = DB::table('users')
             ->select('users.name as user_name','users.lastname as user_lastname', 
             'deceased.name as deceased_name','deceased.lastname as deceased_lastname')
             ->leftJoin('deceased', 'users.id', '=', 'deceased.user_id')
             -> where('user_name', '=', $name)
             -> orWhere('deceased_name', '=', $name)
             -> where('user_type', 3)
             -> where('state', '!=', 4)
             -> orderBy('id', 'DESC')
             -> paginate(15);

        return view('clients.index', compact('clients', 'name'));
    }
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta es valida, el OP esta usando "eloquent" y no "query builder", asi que seria mejor una respuesta con eso

Comment: @karimlema gracias, pero si es como dice JuanRivera, estoy usando eloquent. Y quisiera eso colocarlo en el modelo, ya que no es un parámetro que el cliente tenga q colocar si o si, es un filtro opcional. El cliente ve el listado de los "users" y puede buscar uno por nombre de "user" y/o por nombre de "deceased".